# blazor identity scaffolding ANCM Multiple In-Process Applications in same Process

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I have a blazor server app project. When I was created it I selected individual user account for authentication which gave me the basic register and login pages. Now to edit those pages I need to scaffold the identity area to get the login and register pages.

I scaffold the identity but when I click on login I got

```
HTTP Error 500.35 - ANCM Multiple In-Process Applications in same Process
Common solutions to this issue:
Select a different application pool to create another in-process application.
Specific error detected by ANCM:
Only one in-process application is allowed per IIS application pool. Please assign the application '/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT/Identity/Account/Login' to a different IIS application pool.
Troubleshooting steps:
Check the system event log for error messages
Enable logging the application process' stdout messages
Attach a debugger to the application process and inspect
```

How can I resolve this?
Thanks

Comment: Just scafolding shouln't do this. Try to reproduce this in a new clean project and if you get that error again, post the steps here.

Comment: Ok. I will do that

Comment: The new project works fine after scaffolding identity. For the old project everything was working fine with a crud operation

Comment: Another thing I noticed in the original(previous) project is that extra header and footer was added

Comment: While check I discovered that this link `http://localhost:54888/Identity/Account/Login/Identity/Account/Login` is now getting the login page

Comment: after much investigation I noticed `I noticed multiple _viewimports.cshtml
one in identity/pages/account/_ViewImports.cshtml
another in identity/pages/_ViewImports.cshtml
and another in /pages/_ViewImports.cshtml`

Comment: @HenkHolterman I followed the steps you mentioned but not working. so in the lunchsetting.json. in the applicationUrl, i added Identity/Account/Login" to "http://localhost:54888/ and everything works fine but Identity/Account/Login" is prefix to all link pages